# Separate stdout of an application

Tags: shell, pipe, file-descriptors

I have an application that takes a few command line parameters, then prints some text to the terminal, then starts writing data to a file. It has a parameter I can use to define the file name to write to (like `-o some-file-name.bin`).

I would like to process that data (live) using another application, so I tried making the program output its data to stdout by specifying `-o -` and piping the output to another tool. However, unfortunately, that program isn't smart enough to notice that it is writing to stdout and that it should stop writing human-readable text to stdout (as that messes up the binary data).

So, usually, the tool would write text to stdout (which I don't care about) and data to a file. I would like to ignore all the text written to stdout and instead have it write the data to stdout so I can pipe it into another tool. However when I run it with `-o -`, it writes both the (binary) data and the useless text into stdout, ruining the data.

I tried `-o >( my_other_tool )` instead of a pipe, but that resulted in `Couldn't open output: /dev/fd/63: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory`.

Is there another way - other than recompiling the tool and removing all the useless printf calls - to ignore the original stdout and send the data it would write to a file to stdout instead?

EDIT: In case it is helpful, I am talking about [nsntrace](https://github.com/jonasdn/nsntrace).

Comment: If the program makes use of `-f -` there should also be something like `-q` for "quiet", given it's not done by default. Have you checked that?

Comment: I did check that, and no, there is no option to silence the program. I need to do that externally (or modify the source and recompile it, which I don't really like doing).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're about but try `program -f /dev/fd/3 3>&1 >/dev/null | ...`

Comment: Unfortunately, that also silences the binary data the program is supposed to output (to fd 3).

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: In the link you put in your update `-f` stands for filter while `-o` is the output.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I did use `-o`, and I did try your command @mosvy and it didn't work.

Comment: Yes, it works. Provided, of course, that you're using the `-o`, not the `-f` option: `src/nsntrace -o /dev/fd/3 wget www.google.com 3>&1 >/dev/null | ...`. I supposed you *assumed* that it cannot work. This is really annoying.

Comment: @mosvy `3>&1 1>/dev/null 2>&1` makes it even cleaner.

Comment: I was using the -o option. And the resulting file (with `cat > test` behind the pipe) was empty, and I did test it. However I found out that this was because I called nsntrace with sudo and apparently that's not enough. Did a `sudo su` first and then it worked. Thanks.